# A simple class for getting and printing a string

Tags: c++

I have just started working with classes and in this code I'm trying to have a class which gets a string from the user, counts the length of it and then prints it.
But I'm getting some errors that i can't understand what are they for.
I would appreciate some help.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class String
{
public:
    String();  // constructor
    void Print();   // printing the string
    void Get();     // getting the string from the user.
    int CountLng( char *);   // counting length
    ~String();  // destructor

private:
    char *str;
    int lng;
} str1;


String::String()
{
    lng=0;
    str=NULL;

}


int CountLng( char *str)
{
    char * temp;
    temp=str;
    int size=0;
    while( temp !=NULL)
    {
        size++;
        temp++;
    }

    return size;


};

void String::Get()

{
    str= new char [50];
    cout<<"Enter a string: "<<endl;
    cin>>str;


};


void String::Print()
{
    cout<<"Your string is : "<<str<<endl<<endl;
    lng= CountLng( str);
    cout<<"The length of your string is : "<<lng<<endl<<endl;
};



int main()
{



    str1.Get();
    str1.Print();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it would be hard to help you if you don't tell people what errors you are getting.

Comment: Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall String::CountLng(char *)" (?CountLng@String@@QAEHPAD@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall String::Print(void)" (?Print@String@@QAEXXZ) C:\Users\asus\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TAHW\TAHW\TA1.obj
-------

Comment: and,
Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall String::~String(void)" (??1String@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic atexit destructor for 'str1''(void)" (??__Fstr1@@YAXXZ) C:\Users\asus\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TAHW\TAHW\TA1.obj

Comment: use String class name before method: `int String::CountLng( char *str)`. Also, you didn't define a destructor body

Comment: I did and now it gives me just one error:

Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall String::~String(void)" (??1String@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic atexit destructor for 'str1''(void)" (??__Fstr1@@YAXXZ) C:\Users\asus\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TAHW\TAHW\TA1.obj

Answer (score 1):

In the `CountLng()` method, to check for the end of the string, you need to check the content of the location the pointer points to , not the pointer location itself:

```
while( *temp !='\0')//*temp gives you the value but temp gives you the memory location
{
    size++;
    temp++;
}
```

A standard of of checking string end is looking for character `'\0'` or `NUL`. A pointer pointing to the end of a string does not has to be NULL.

Moreover, in the `Get()` method your string size is limited to 50 characters. This will be a problem when adding two String objects together. You need to make string size dynamic by using std::copy and reallocationg your char array and make your string size bigger in the case of an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

1. `int CountLng(char *str)` should be `int String::CountLng(char *str)` because it is the method of `String` class.
2. Also, you defined your destructor in class declaration, but didn't define his body:

`String::~String()
{
}`

Answer (score -1):

Above code got multiple problems

1. You are using str1 a supposed to be string object, but not declaring it.
2. Member functions are declared with :: syntax
3. Destructor got no body

I have tweaked your program to get rid of these issues, compare it with your original prog to see the difference

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class String
{
public:
    String();  // constructor
    void Print();   // printing the string
    void Get();     // getting the string from the user.
    int CountLng( char *);   // counting length
    ~String(){ if (str) delete []str; };  // destructor

private:
    char *str;
    int lng;
};


String::String()
{
    lng=0;
    str=NULL;

}


int String::CountLng( char *str)
{
    char * temp;
    temp=str;
    int size=0;
    while( *temp !='\0')
    {
        size++;
        temp++;
    }

    return size;


};

void String::Get()

{
    str= new char [50];
    cout<<"Enter a string: "<<endl;
    cin>>str;


};


void String::Print()
{
    cout<<"Your string is : "<<str<<endl<<endl;
    lng= CountLng( str);
    cout<<"The length of your string is : "<<lng<<endl<<endl;
};



int main()
{

    String str1;

    str1.Get();
    str1.Print();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```